# Problems with 5 monitor setup and DisplayPort splitter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I'm setting up five displays on a system that has a 4 mini-DisplayPort graphics card.  The graphics card supports up to 6 heads.  I cannot simply switch to a card that has 5-6 ports due to space limitation (unless it was extremely low profile).

My configuration:
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Using gnome in place of Unity
-- output of ps aux: gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback --disable-acceleration-check
- Five monitors - 3 connected directly via mini-DisplayPort, with two others connected using [Club DisplayPort splitter](http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/mst-hub-1-3.html)
- I set the monitors up using xrandr and then captured this config by creating a monitors.xml with the Display settings console

Problem:
- On average, 1 of 4 boots does not properly read the monitors.xml.
- When it doesn't, the resolution and rotation are not correct.  It goes to the default setup of extending them next to each other in a horizontal orientation (I lose the rotation and non-standard resolutions).

What I've tried:

- I've found reports of forgotten settings and tried most of these fixes without any improvement.
  [Ubuntu - forgetting screens prefs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1292398)
- I've tried manually settings with xrandr after an arbitrary sleep (15 seconds) at boot.  This often resulted in the MST splitter not even recognizing the monitors on the splitter (say 25-35% of time).
- I'm thinking that maybe this might be a timing issue where it takes longer for the MST splitter to initialize?

Next steps:

- I tried moving the splitter to the first port of the video card to see if it would initialize faster.  I'm going to be performing some testing to see if this resulted in any change.
- Look into a udev rule that would wait for the splitter monitors to be found, and then manually run xrandr.  This seems to do exactly what monitors.xml is doing, however, with the unity-settings-daemon and xrandr module.

Any thoughts or experiences with this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue did appear to be related to the timing of the initialization of the monitors.  Switching the MST splitter to the first port resulted in the system successfully processing the monitors.xml file every time.  It has been restarted many times now without issue.